# Installing ODP.net on the client and server machines

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

I am installing ODP.net on the client and server machines to support the new ODP.net data provider provided by Oracle for .net 4 and above. How do I install this dlls is there any installer provided for easy installations. I tried OUI installer provided on Oracle website and it seems to be installing the oracle db client. Can anyone plz guide me on this installation and setup on client and server machines for 32 and 64 bit machines (for client - server application).

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the managed provider or the standard one?

Comment: ODP.NET, Unmanaged driver does rely on the Oracle client libraries. ODP.NET. Managed Driver does not (but has limitiations in functionality). If you want to install the unmanaged driver, take a look at the "Xcopy" install, which gives you more control over how it is packaged and installed: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html